# Winapi, change the color of groupbox frame

Tags: user-interface, winapi, frame, groupbox

I want to make dark semitransparent GUI using WinAPI. I made a custom button, but I cant make my own groupbox. In `WM_DRAWITEM` case of message handler, the callback drawing my groupbox is not even called. This callback contains MessageBox call that is not even once appeared.

How to draw groupbox with colored frame and colored text? Also I want to make my groupboxes lying under the all other controls. How to do that?

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    // Main logic goes here...
    ShowMainWindow();
}

void RegisterWndClass(WNDPROC Proc, LPCTSTR szName, UINT brBackground)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(wc);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = Proc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0x14, 0x14, 0x14));
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = szName;
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Cannot register class"), TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);
    }
}

// Draw custom button
void DrawButton(DRAWITEMSTRUCT *Item, HWND hwnd)
{

    SelectObject(Item->hDC, CreateFont(16, 0, 0, 0, FW_NORMAL, 0, 0, 0, DEFAULT_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH, "Arial Black"));
    FillRect(Item->hDC, &Item->rcItem, CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0x14, 0x14, 0x14)));
    SelectObject(Item->hDC, CreateSolidBrush(0));
    if (Item->itemState & ODS_SELECTED)
    {
        SetTextColor(Item->hDC, 0);
        SelectObject(Item->hDC, CreateSolidBrush(0xFF00));
        SelectObject(Item->hDC, CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 2, 0xFF00));
    }
    else
    {
        SetTextColor(Item->hDC, 0x00FF00);
        SelectObject(Item->hDC, CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 2, 0x00FF00));

    }
    SetBkMode(Item->hDC, TRANSPARENT);
    RoundRect(Item->hDC, Item->rcItem.left, Item->rcItem.top, Item->rcItem.right, Item->rcItem.bottom, 20, 20);
    int len = GetWindowTextLength(Item->hwndItem);
    LPSTR lpBuff[255];
    GetWindowTextA(Item->hwndItem, lpBuff, len + 1);
    DrawTextA(Item->hDC, lpBuff, len, &Item->rcItem, DT_CENTER);
}

// Trying to draw customgroupbox
void DrawKeyGroup(DRAWITEMSTRUCT *Item, HWND hwnd)
{
    SelectObject(Item->hDC, CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 255, 0)));
    SelectObject(Item->hDC, CreateSolidBrush(0));

    SetTextColor(Item->hDC, 0x00FF00);
    SelectObject(Item->hDC, CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 2, 0x00FF00));
    MessageBox(NULL, "", "", MB_OK);

    //SetBkMode(Item->hDC, TRANSPARENT);
    RoundRect(Item->hDC, Item->rcItem.left, Item->rcItem.top, Item->rcItem.right, Item->rcItem.bottom, 200, 200);
}

//Main windows proc
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HDC hDC;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    RECT rect;

    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE: // Init interface
        // Text field
        CreateWindow(TEXT("EDIT"),
            NULL,
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | ES_LEFT | ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
            10, 280, 350, 20,
            hWnd,
            (HMENU)ID_KEY_FIELD,
            NULL,
            NULL);
        // Button to enter the text
        CreateWindowEx(0, TEXT("BUTTON"),
            TEXT("Unlock"),
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_OWNERDRAW,
            370, 280, 150, 20,
            hWnd,
            (HMENU)ID_KEY_ENTER,
            GetModuleHandle(NULL),
            NULL);
        // Groupbox
        CreateWindowEx(0, TEXT("BUTTON"),
            TEXT("Key"),
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_GROUPBOX | BS_OWNERDRAW,
            5, 262, 523, 47,
            hWnd,
            (HMENU)ID_KEY_GROUP,
            GetModuleHandle(NULL), 
            NULL);
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        hDC = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    // Color text field
    case WM_CTLCOLOREDIT:
    {
        HDC hdc = (HDC)wParam;
        HWND hwnd = (HWND)lParam;
        if (GetDlgCtrlID(hwnd) == ID_KEY_FIELD)
        {
            SetTextColor(hdc, 0xFF00);
            SetBkColor(hdc, RGB(0x29, 0x29, 0x29));
            return (LRESULT)CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0x29, 0x29, 0x29));
        }
        break;
    }
    // Color statie elements (group box caption)
    /*case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
        SetTextColor((HDC)wParam, RGB(0x00, 0x8C, 0xBA));

        SetBkMode((HDC)wParam, TRANSPARENT);
        SetBkColor((HDC)wParam, RGB(0x14, 0x14, 0x14));

        return (LRESULT)CreateSolidBrush(GetBkColor((HDC)wParam));*/
    // Draw custom controls
    case WM_DRAWITEM:
    {
        DRAWITEMSTRUCT *dis = (DRAWITEMSTRUCT*)lParam;
        switch (dis->CtlID)
        {
        case ID_KEY_ENTER:
            DrawButton(dis, GetDlgItem(hWnd, dis->CtlID));
            break;
        case ID_KEY_GROUP:
            DrawKeyGroup(dis, GetDlgItem(hWnd, dis->CtlID));
            break;
        }
    }
    case WM_SIZE:
        break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

void ShowMainWindow(void)
{
    HWND hMainWnd;
    MSG msg;

    RegisterWndClass(WndProc, TEXT("Info"), COLOR_WINDOW);

    hMainWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_LAYERED, TEXT("Info"), TEXT("Info"),
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, 550, 360, (HWND)NULL, (HMENU)NULL,
        GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    SetWindowLong(hMainWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(hMainWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_LAYERED);
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hMainWnd, 0, (255 * 70) / 100, LWA_ALPHA);

    if (!hMainWnd)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Can\'t create main window."), TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);
        return;
    }

    ShowWindow(hMainWnd, SW_SHOW);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: A groupbox would have to be the simplest control there is, just roll your own if you want to customise it beyond what the control allows.

Comment: You will have to draw your groupboxes in `WM_PAINT`, then you will have to properly position your controls by handling `WM_SIZE` and `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED`...